# Sorting shorthands alphanumerically/naturally

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In my thesis, I have a list of shorthands for the various manuscripts I am using. How can I sort it alphanumerically/naturally so that the order is *A1, a7, a11* (because 7 comes before 11) instead of the default *A1, a11, a7* (because 7 comes after 1)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    tools=manuscripts,
    bibstyle=unified,
]{biblatex-multiple-dm}

\usepackage[
    bibstyle=multiple-dm,
    citestyle=unified,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@manuscript{kc:vorau,
    dating      = {4.~Viertel 12.~Jh.},
    library     = {Stiftsarchiv},
    location    = {Vorau},
    shelfmark   = {Ms~276},
    shorthand   = {A1},
    sortkey     = {kc:A01},
    sorttitle   = {kc:A01},
    sortyear    = {1176},
    keywords    = {mss},
}

@manuscript{kc:klagenfurt,
    dating      = {2.~Hälfte 12.~Jh.},
    library     = {Kärntner Landesarchiv},
    location    = {Klagenfurt},
    shelfmark   = {Cod.~GV 6/26},
    shorthand   = {a7},
    sortkey     = {kc:a07},
    sorttitle   = {kc:a07},
    sortyear    = {1151},
    keywords    = {mss},
}

@manuscript{kc:nuernberg,
    dating      = {1.~Hälfte 13.~Jh.},
    doi         = {10.11588/diglit.28408},
    library     = {Germanisches Nationalmuseum},
    location    = {Nürnberg},
    shelfmark   = {Hs.~22067},
    shorthand   = {a11},
    sortkey     = {kc:a11},
    sorttitle   = {kc:a11},
    sortyear    = {1201},
    keywords    = {mss},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printshorthands[keyword=mss]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sortshorthand` to force a slightly different order for `shorthand`s. If you add leading zeros to the shorthands in `sortshorthand` you get the desired order. (You are already doing something similar with `sortkey` for other sorting schemes.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  tools=manuscripts,
  bibstyle=unified,
]{biblatex-multiple-dm}

\usepackage[
  bibstyle=multiple-dm,
  citestyle=unified,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@manuscript{kc:vorau,
  dating      = {4.~Viertel 12.~Jh.},
  library     = {Stiftsarchiv},
  location    = {Vorau},
  shelfmark   = {Ms~276},
  sortshorthand = {A01},
  shorthand   = {A1},
  sortkey     = {kc:A01},
  sorttitle   = {kc:A01},
  sortyear    = {1176},
  keywords    = {mss},
}
@manuscript{kc:klagenfurt,
  dating      = {2.~Hälfte 12.~Jh.},
  library     = {Kärntner Landesarchiv},
  location    = {Klagenfurt},
  shelfmark   = {Cod.~GV 6/26},
  sortshorthand = {a07},
  shorthand   = {a7},
  sortkey     = {kc:a07},
  sorttitle   = {kc:a07},
  sortyear    = {1151},
  keywords    = {mss},
}

@manuscript{kc:nuernberg,
  dating      = {1.~Hälfte 13.~Jh.},
  doi         = {10.11588/diglit.28408},
  library     = {Germanisches Nationalmuseum},
  location    = {Nürnberg},
  shelfmark   = {Hs.~22067},
  sortshorthand = {a11},
  shorthand   = {a11},
  sortkey     = {kc:a11},
  sorttitle   = {kc:a11},
  sortyear    = {1201},
  keywords    = {mss},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printshorthands[keyword=mss]
\end{document}
```

[image: A1 Vorau: Stiftsarchiv, Ms 276. 4. Viertel 12. Jh. a7 Klagenfurt: Kärntner Landesarchiv, Cod. GV 6/26. 2. Hälfte 12. Jh. a11 Nürnberg: Germanisches Nationalmuseum, Hs. 22067. 1. Hälfte 13. Jh.]

Comment: I had missed `sortshorthand` +1. But is the screenshot correct?

Comment: So had I. Anyhow, `sortshorthand` indeed yields the intended result for me.

Comment: @gusbrs Ugh. A typo left over from an earlier experiment. Fixed now.